# Best way for a class to access a private method (private name mangling)

Tags: python

If I have this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def A(self):
        __doA()

def __doA():
    print 'A'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(1)
    t.A()
```

It will obviously result in a `NameError: global name '_Test__doA' is not defined`

According to the docs:

> When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier __spam occurring in a class named Ham will be transformed to _Ham__spam. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used. If the transformed name is extremely long (longer than 255 characters), implementation defined truncation may happen. If the class name consists only of underscores, no transformation is done.

I want to maintain the two underscores as the module will be used by many people and I was to symbolize that the methods are private, however I still want the class to be able to access them.

One quick workaround is to change the method name to end in two underscores as well to get around the name mangling:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def A(self):
        __doA__()

def __doA__():
    print 'A'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(1)
    t.A()
```

I'm not sure how Pythonic that is to have a private method end in two underscores as well.

Another, less elegant way IMO is this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.__doA = globals()['__doA']
    def A(self):
        self.__doA()

def __doA():
    print 'A'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(1)
    t.A()
```

Is there a better way to access a private method from inside of a class in python?

Comment: That's not a method, it's just a function. Name mangling breaks here, because Python mangles the name into the class when the function is really just `__doA`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: why not just `def A(self): globals()["__doA"]()` ? but this has horrible code smell ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to call a private function from my class. In this example `__doA` would be something that is called from many other functions and is quite large.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I could do that, I'm just not sure if there is a more Pythonic way, etc. to accomplish what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short script to recreate the error:

```
def __foo(x):
    print x

__foo("foo")

class Bar(object):
    def baz(self, x):
        __foo(x)


Bar().baz("foo")
```

Which results in:

```
foo # direct call works

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    Bar().baz("foo")
  File "C:/Python27/test.py", line 8, in baz
    __foo(x)
NameError: global name '_Bar__foo' is not defined # gets mangled in class, breaks
```

You shouldn't give functions (as distinct from methods) names with leading double underscores, as this breaks name mangling when you try to access them from inside classes - the function becomes unreachable, as there's no class name to mangle onto the front of it.

If you want to indicate a function is private use a single leading underscore, but [we're all consenting adults here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html).

Comment: I understand how name mangling works, that's not the issue. Coming from a Java background I was under the assumption one underscore is generally for `protected` members while two is for `private`. Is that wrong?

Comment: @ZWiki Python doesn't really have equivalents of protected and private - single underscore is private by convention (*"please stay out"*), double underscore (per [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)) should be used to avoid name clashes and is sometimes (mis?)used for further privacy (*"seriously, please stay out"*), but **neither is unreachable**.